# Ember.js/Handlebars nothing showing in template

Tags: ember.js

In an Ember.js/ember-data app, I have this route:

```
  this.resource 'event', path: '/events/:event_id'
```

When accessing a URL, the data is being loaded via an Ajax call to my API. But inside my template, I can't get any data to be printed.

For example, I have this in my template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

Yet the `title` attribute, which is not null, is not displayed. Am I missing something or what is going on?

Comment: Are you using the Ember `set` method to set the title attribute? Ember doesn't know to update the template if you just assign the value with the equals operator. You should include your code and templates.

Comment: No, I'm not using `set` to set anything. It was my understanding that once the model is loaded using ember-data, it is available in the template. Is that not the case? Do I need to do something else?

Comment: No, that should be fine. Is the problem specific to your ajax call? Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/JNLPZ/) that shows how the bindings should work.

Comment: Hmmm. That's exactly what I thought it should be like. I'm not sure why I'm not able to access the model's attributes in my template.

Comment: If you post what you have I would be happy to look at it.

Comment: After some more debugging it seems it may have something to do with my model definition or the (de)serializing of it. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/mdi/5078155) of appropriate code.

Comment: At first glance I don't see anything out of the ordinary. Does it work if you remove the custom transform? If you can reproduce the behaviour in a jsfiddle it might be easier to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. It's because I was using the underscored attribute names instead of the camelCased ones. Sorry...